# On unknown transition in equations proving the upper-bound of complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I'm reading [2] and got stuck in understanding the transition from the first to the second lines. I thought it was because of bivariate Taylor series expansion but couldn't quite reproduce this transition.
Could someone explain it to me?

### Notation

- K is a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$
- $\omega \in \Omega$ where $\Omega$ is a fundamental parallelogram
- $g(w, z) = (1 - \frac{z}{\omega}) \exp (\frac{z}{\omega} + \frac{1}{2} (\frac{z}{\omega})^2)$ such that we were discussing to define the Weierstrass sigma-function; $\sigma(z) = z . \prod_{\omega \in \Omega - {0}} g(w, z)$.

### Transition of interest (Page 93 of [2])

[image]

### Reference

[2] Jones, Gareth A., and David Singerman. Complex functions: an algebraic and geometric viewpoint. Cambridge university press, 1987.

Comment: It looks like it should follow from the formal expansion of $\log$, i.e., $\log (1+x) = x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \cdots$.

Comment: oh! That makes sense! Thank you so much!